# How to render a jmx attribute as a graph int jminix

Tags: java, jmx, web-client, jminix

The new version of [jminix (1.1.0)](http://code.google.com/p/jminix/) allows things like [this](http://code.google.com/p/jminix/wiki/Screenshots) (graph example).

How would you actually do this?

It *looks* like I have to write custom code to generate that graph as HTML?

If so, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Because that page uses a [Dijit tree control](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Tree.html) inside a [Dijit Border container](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html). Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: I think so :) what control is generating the graph?

Comment: The Dijit tree control I already mentioned in my first comment.  The lazy loading of the tree (the JMX tree is loaded each time you fold open a node) seems to be implemented using (dojo/store/JsonRest)[http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#dojo-store-jsonrest]